# Java RMI Connect Exception: Connection Timeout expection

Tags: java, rmi, connection-timeout

I am working on a Java RMI code which is throwing this exception. I am actually trying it only on one laptop ie same is the client and the server. SO why the connection time out problem at all.

The code is working fine on other laptops, so there is no problem with the code. I changed the IP addresses accordingly so no problem with the ip addresses. The client side program is working fine but the server program is throwing these exceptions.

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you starting registry before starting programs? Add some code here, which shows how you are connecting, and stack trace.

Comment: Yes, i am doing everything. See, the program is working on other laptops without any problem. In my laptop, i cant even see my ip address. It says "Media Disconnected". Does not show the ipv4 address. Why is that?? I think there is a problem with that, but i dont know what.

Comment: Use loopback address (127.0.0.1) to connect

Comment: Clearly you have a problem with the computer itself, not RMI. Probably nothing works that needs a network.